# ¿Qué puerto TCP usa el programa ping?

Tags: linux, consola, centos, redes, tcp

En el modelo `TCP` y en el programa *`Ping`* ¿puede enviarse por algún puerto? o en está capa no se usan puertos.

Comment: Mira esta respuesta: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/37897/28079 y consulta la guía __[ask]__ para la próxima.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Básicamente NO, `Ping` usa [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) cuya capa no tiene el concepto de port.

Los puertos pertenecen a los protocolos de la capa de transporte como:

- `TCP`
- `UDP`

Comment: Interesante mencionar también que concretamente usa un mecanismo de ICMP llamado petición de eco (echo request).

La versión en español del enlace de la Wikipedia sería https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

Amigo el protocolo de eco o ICMP es un protocolo de capa 3 del modelo OSI.

TCP es un protocolo de capa 4 o capa de transporte, son dos protocolos totalmente diferentes, ademas tienes una seria confusión con los puertos lógicos, cada puerto representa un **servicio**, sea html *puerto 80*, ftp *puerto 21 y 22*, htmls *puerto 443* etc.

Los puertos lógicos son parte del protocolo de la capa de transporte, sea TCP o UDP.